# Part titles in smallcaps

Tags: titlesec, parts

I would like all parts, chapters, sections etc to have their titles in smallcaps. To do this, I tried:
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}

and this worked for chapters, sections, etc, but not for parts. I see in the documentation for titlesec that parts are an exception and you need to use the advanced options. I did my best to understand how, but I'm afraid I'm too much of a beginner (well, not strictly true, I've used LaTeX for 20 years, but just not done any such fine tuning before).

As I understand it, I should use this command:
\titleformat{\part}[?]{sc}{?}{?}{?}[?]

If I ONLY want to change the titles to smallcaps, and I don't want to change anything else about the standard part titles, what should I do? I also tried the sectsty package, but it didn't work with the extbook class, which I need to use because I want 14pt text.

Comment: Maybe try `\titleformat*{\part}{\scshape}`?

Comment: @Bernard Did you try it?

Comment: @egreg: No, I didn't have time. That's  why I  wrote  ‘Maybe’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual of `titlesec` shows how to get the same output as the standard `book` class. Just replace `\bfseries` with `\scshape`.

For `\part` it would be more involved and the simplest strategy is to patch the relevant commands.

I used the `book` class, but the code below also works with `\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}` (but the font is really too big).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\bfseries}{\scshape}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@part}{\bfseries}{\scshape}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@spart}{\bfseries}{\scshape}{}{}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\scshape}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\scshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\part{Test}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}
\paragraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! (The reason I'm using 14pt is that I'll use this for bookbinding, so these A4 pages are going to end up as A5 pages with the pdfpages package).